# Reading from two differerent text files and get each line's column

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I'd like to read from two different text files (row numbers are equal) and compare each row's 5th column with each other. But it did not work for me. Is there anyone help me ? Here my code:

```
df -h --total>current_filesystem_usage.txt
if [ -s previous_months_filesystem_usage.txt ]
then 
  #reading from two different files and store each line into a variable
    while read current_file_line <&3 && read previous_file_line <&4
     do

    current_filesystem_name=$(cat $current_file_line | awk {'print $1'})
    current_filesystem_usage=$(cat $current_file_line | awk {'print $5'})

    previous_filesystem_name=$(cat $previous_file_line | awk {'print $1'})
    previous_filesystem_usage=$(cat $previous_file_line | awk {'print $5'})

    if [ ${current_filesystem_usage%?} -ge ${previous_filesystem_usage%?} ]
           then echo "There is problem !!! "
            echo "Current disk usage:${current_filesystem_name}, ${current_filesystem_usage}"
            echo "Previous month's disk usage:${previous_filesystem_name}, ${previous_filesystem_usage}"
        #I also want to store all echo output to output.txt file

    elif [ ${current_filesystem_usage%?} -lt ${previous_filesystem_usage%?} ]
             then echo "There is no problem. Everything is alright."
              echo "Current disk usage: ${current_filesystem_name}, ${current_filesystem_usage}"
              echo "Previous month's disk usage: ${previous_filesystem_name}, ${previous_filesystem_usage}"
       fi

         done 3<current_filesystem_usage.txt 4<previous_months_filesystem_usage.txt

fi
```

Comment: If you want to compare and calculate difference, you may use not `-m` instead of  `-h`. It will output result as megabytes as integer value, rather than human-readable but not well parsed form.

Comment: I want to compare percentage of usages. not megabytes bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {               # process the first file
    a[FNR]=$5           # hash field $5 to a, use row number as key
    next }              # move to next record
$5 > a[FNR] {           # process the second file, if current is greater than previous
    print "error"       # output error
}
' file1 file2
```

It basically hashes file1 to `a` and uses row number as key. You did not mention in your post what the result of the comparison is, so can't help more ATM.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit ? For example, what is a and why you start with $0 ?

Comment: The result of comparison, if current is greater than previous echo error, if not , everything is alright.

Comment: `a` is a hash where `$5` is stored when `file1` is processed, row number as the key.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I really appreciate that. I will try.

Comment: With better requirements I probably could help more.